# JavaScript increment Operator ins't incrementing by 1

Tags: javascript, clock

I am creating clock in JavaScript but when i increment the seconds by one using increment operator the value is increment by * 2 .

```
var hours=0;
var sec=0;
var min=0;

function clock(){

    document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML= ++sec;
    if(sec>59){
        document.getElementById("min").innerHTML= ++min;
        sec=0;
    } else if(min>59){
        document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = ++hours;
        min=0;
    }
    else if(hours>12){
        hours=0;
    }
    setInterval(clock, 1000);
}
clock();
```

Comment: Setinterval isn't precise, don't try to use it for a clock.

Comment: Any other function ??

Comment: You can not be using else if and you should not be using setInterval inside of a function that is being called with setInterval.

Comment: If you want to make a clock, use the date-time model provided by the language, possibly with Moment.

Comment: http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 2):

You should not be using else if.

You should not be using setInterval inside of the clock function. It should be setTimeout. Using setInterval, means on every iteration, you are adding another interval.

Thirdly setTimeout/setInterval is not accurate. You should really just use a start date and subtract the current date and determine the time difference.

Comment: var d = new Date();
 var h = d.getHours();
 var m = d.getMinutes();
 var sec = d.getSeconds();
       document.getElementById("sec").innerHTML= h;
         document.getElementById("min").innerHTML= m;
 document.getElementById("hours").innerHTML = sec;

Comment: i have changed my code and it is working now can you tell me how i can call this function again and again ??

Answer (score 0):

@epascarello also right. But another thing.

when you use increment operator, add `++` ****AFTER**** a variable.

change to:

```js
++sec to sec++
++min to min++
++hours to hours++
```